# Is there a best place to search for the Daedra banishing enchantment?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just started a new game and getting the Daedra banishing enchantment is high on my list of things to do early on.  With it, I can turn simple iron daggers into a huge profit which will open a lot of doors for me early in the game.

It seems that finding a weapn with this enchantment is all random, but I am wondering if these weapons show up more in a particular area or if it depends on my level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lowest tier of weapon that can have banish is Elven, they start to show up at level 22. Check the stores and the boss chests in dungeons. Doesn't matter where you look.

Comment: I've since confirmed through two playthroughs that level 22 is indeed the level when items enchanted with Daedra banishing become available in merchant shops.  As soon as I reach level 22, I hop all over Skyrim holds until I find a merchant who sells it.

Answer (score 1):

In both of my playthroughs, I have found it on an item from a merchant first. Check all of your merchants, particularly the smiths, as they have a large array of weapons.